# Google Chrome does not synchronize between Desktop Environments

Tags: debian, ubuntu, desktop-environment

I installed `Ubuntu 18` on my machine and I am evaluating different Desktop Environments (like Deepin, Unity, Wayland, etc) in order to check which one is more productive for my daily tasks.

The problem is: every time I change the Desktop Environment (e.g. from Unity to another), Google Chrome does not recognize my stored logins anymore. And even the synchronization function does not work properly.

Is it expected that the applications work differently based on the running Desktop Environment? I was assuming that for them, it should be transparent.